# Length of a string is not what I was expecting

Tags: c#, string, dictionary

The following method produces unexpected output:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            {       2, "0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010".Replace(" ", "") },
            {       0, "0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000".Replace(" ", "") },
            { 7529548, "0000 0000 ‭0111 0010 1110 0100 0100 1100‬".Replace(" ", "") }
        };

        foreach(var pair in dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pair.Value.Length);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

And the output is:
**32, 32, 34**

And it doesn't change if I play with compiler settings.

Why could this happen? Why might the string length be different in that last case?

Comment: There are extra invisible characters in your last string. Dictionary unrelated.

Comment: "*Dictionary<int, string> is broken. C#. .NET 4.7.2*" is an explosive statement and needs extraordinary proof

Comment: BTW, you would figure it out if you had **minimized** your example: [mcve].

Comment: The easiest way to spot these issues is to navigate through the string, character by character, by pressing the right arrow. If you press right arrow **and the cursor doesn't move** then there is a hidden character nearby.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your last binary string literal:

- before the `0111`, there’s a U+202D LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE
- after the `1100`, there’s a U+202C POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING

Remove those invisible characters and you’ll get the length-in-codepoints you expect.